# Copy video while cutting frames

Tags: matlab, video

I have a video written with the Xvid MPEG4-Codec. Unfortunately, each frame has an annoying bar to the right and to the bottom of a couple of pixels. What I would like to do is to remove this bar, preferably using MATLAB.

For this purpose, I have written this code to try this out:

```
function [] = changeVideo(in_path, out_path, reqSize)
    videoList = dir(strcat(in_path, '\*.avi'));
    for ii = 1:numel(videoList)
        vidReader = VideoReader(strcat([in_path '\'], videoList(ii).name));
        vidWriter = VideoWriter(strcat([out_path '\'], videoList(ii).name),'MPEG-4');
        open(vidWriter);
        while hasFrame(vidReader)
            % here I would change the size of the frame
            writeVideo(vidWriter,readFrame(vidReader));
        end
        close(vidWriter);
        close(vidReader);
    end
end
```

Unfortunately, this does not seem to work. The resulting video has a different memory footprint and quality than the original video. Since MATLAB can read the original video, I was hoping that there is a way to replicate this video, but only change each frame slightly in its size. Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: The original video is compressed. Matlab decode (decompress) the video, and encode (compress) it back. The process reduces quality. In order to keep quality, you need tool that can resize video in the ["compressed domain"](http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/2002/HPL-2002-282.html). It's not supported by Matalb.

Comment: Try using ffmpeg: [http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4563/how-can-i-crop-a-video-with-ffmpeg](http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4563/how-can-i-crop-a-video-with-ffmpeg)